# Override Default behavior in Entity Framework database first

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

Working in an ongoing ASP.NET Core application, recently updated to v7.0, utilizing SQL Server database. We scaffold from the existing database (database-first model).

On my first time to scaffold and add some additional tables since moving to .NET 7.0, I'm running into issues... because most of our BIT columns in the database have a default constraint, and as stated here https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10840 :

> If a BIT column has a DEFAULT constraint, we make the property nullable regardless of whether it has a NOT NULL constraint. This allow you to use the default value in EF.

So.... after scaffolding I'm getting hundreds of errors for columns that are defined as `BIT NOT NULL` but the model shows as `bool?` (nullable) because of this change.

Is there a command option in scaffolding to override this behavior, so that our default constraint in the database can remain, but our columns are still defined as `NOT NULL` within the application? I've seen mention of changing the `.HasDefaultValueSql()` setting, but that only applies to code-first implementations, not database-first.

Comment: EF Core Power Tools allows you to.override the behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've seen mention of changing the .HasDefaultValueSql() setting, but that only applies to code-first implementations, not database-first.

There is no real difference between code-first and database-first any more.  It's all technically code-first, even if the code-first configuration is generated from the database metadata.  So any solution that works in code-first can be adapted to your scenario.

If you don't like how the entities are generated you can now [customize the reverse-engineering templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/templates?tabs=dotnet-core-cli).

Comment: Thanks for the note.  I've read through the article you highlighted, installed the templates. I'm not seeing what I would change to override the scaffolding behavior of changing the NOT NULL bit to NULL.  I see nothing comparable to the HasDefaultValueSql setting.

Comment: Also there's nothing wrong with search/replace `bool?` with `bool` in the generated files.